# loopback 4 legacy juggler replaceById and updateById adds unwanted id field to embedded documents in mongodb

Tags: loopback4

When i use findById, replaceById or updateById of legacy-juggler with mongodb, an unwanted id field is added to every nested object

Steps to reproduce

```
//the model
export class NestedDoc extends Model{
  @Property() myProp1?: string;
  @Property() myProp2?: number;
}

export class MyEntity extends Entity {
  @Property({
    type: 'string',
    id: true,
  })
  id: string;

  @Property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @Property() nested?: NestedDoc;
}


//in the controller
await this.MyEntityRepository.replaceById( myEntity.id, myEntity );
```

Current Behavior

after the update/replace, the result in the db is

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f228e05ae69644ed8f31445"
  },
  "name": "entityname",
  "nested": {
    "id": null,
    "myProp1": "prop1",
    "myProp2": 2
  }
}
```

Expected Behavior:

do not add "id" fields to nested objects

Additional information:
When replacing document a warning appear in console:
`WARNING: id property cannot be changed from 5f228e05ae69644ed8f31445 to 5f228e05ae69644ed8f31445 for model:MyEntity in 'loaded' operation hook`

*edit. THIS ALSO HAPPEN WITH updateById

*edit. also findById returns undefined id for nested objects, also if in the db that field does not exists

```
versions:
win32 x64 13.10.1

+-- @loopback/authorization@0.6.2
+-- @loopback/boot@2.3.5
+-- @loopback/context@3.9.2
+-- @loopback/core@2.9.1
+-- @loopback/express@1.2.5
+-- @loopback/http-server@2.1.9
+-- @loopback/openapi-v3@3.4.5
+-- @loopback/repository@2.9.0
+-- @loopback/security@0.2.14
+-- @loopback/service-proxy@2.3.4
+-- loopback-connector-mongodb@5.2.2
```

*EDIT
After many test i see that the issue is only on the findById that returns that non-existent id fields. The corrupt data was then saved to db in other parts of the code that I had not seen

Comment: For future reference, this question has been posted elsewhere: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/6029